# German student residence application with Belgium residence permit

Tags: resident-permit

I am an Indian national, currently in Belgium with a Belgium residence permit valid until next year. I have received a PHD project work acceptance from Germany. Can I apply for a German student residence permit based on my Belgium residence permit validity?